# Sending large number of messages using spring jmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is there a best practice or guidance for sending persistent messages with `asyncSend` set to true.

We don't have transaction manager configured

We have ~40k-50k messages which are sent using jmsTemplate configured with

```
org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory
```

We have a for loop which iterates over messages list and send them using

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, msg)
```

We see lot of message loss on frequent basis, when we turn off `asyncSend` we get the reliability but the producer performance drops by 95%

Comment: Is it the same when you are using it on localhost? I would try to test it with other JMS provider to narrow down on which side of communication is problem (if it's not some lower level problem: e.g. transport layer).

Comment: @Ikrnac No producer java client , activemq broker sits on different physical boxes. It can be a transport layer problem I agree, what I am looking at is there any best way to have good reliability with decent performance

Comment: I was suggesting some investigation approaches. To prove it's not transport layer, locate them on same machine. If it is not transport layer, change JMS provider (e.g. HornetQ is easy to use) to find out if Spring or ActiveMQ is causing problems.

Comment: BTW, I bet this is something Stack Overflow can't help you with

Comment: Can you provide the code ? Are you using persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of speculation as the question is not very detailed but anyway.

Depending on configuration, ActiveMQ might have memory limits on queues (might as well differ between persistent and non persistent messages). So when memory is up, your `asyncSend` calls will ignore warnings and continue to deliver messages to the "black hole" until memory is freed by the consumer.

There is no silver bullet to allow max performance and max reliability. Unfortunately.

However, I would try setting a `producerWindowSize` on the connection factory to allow some specified amount of data before a broker ack is received. Exact value is something you need to try out and depends on scenario as well as broker config/resources.

Comment: Once I set "producerWindowSize", will producer wait for receiving ack for all the previously sent messages?

Comment: ProducerWindowSize helped us , there are almost no message loss under peak load. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using a [ProducerCallback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/ProducerCallback.html)

```
List<String> messageTexts = prepareListOfMessaeTexts();
ProducerCallback producerCallback = (session, producer) -> {
    Topic destination = session.createTopic(myTopicName);
    for (String messageText : myMessagmessageTextseBodies) {
        producer.send(destination, session.createTextMessage(messageText));
    }
    return null;
};
jmsTemplate.execute(producerCallback);
```